# file name without extension

Tags: php

Is there any method of obtaining the name of the file uploaded to a server without extension, in PHP? I used the `$_FILES['file']['name']` but it returns the extension too.

Comment: wow you get 5 seperate answers/methods that all do the same thing! happy days!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
$filename = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

[pathinfo](http://php.net/pathinfo) is a core PHP function since 4.0.3, and the PATHINFO_FILENAME option was added in 5.2.

Answer (score 3):

Use PHP [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function.

```
string basename ( string $path [, string $suffix ] )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pathinfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it as:

```
$filenameOnly = array_pop(array_reverse(explode(".", $yourfilename)));
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('^(.*)\..+?$', $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) or use a regex to do it indiscriminately:

```
preg_replace('/(.*)\\.[^\\.]*/', '$1', $filename);
```